# Flex/AS3 error I don't understand (net.registerClassAlias)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

On a large inherited project I am getting the error below. So far I haven't even found where the error is being triggered. I've searched on various terms (I'm using Flash Builder) and find no references to `registerClassAlias` and only one reference to `DataItem` (below).

I am assuming that `_ShoppingCart_FlexInit` is some internal Flex call.

Does anyone understand this error: what is causing it and how to resolve it? The suggestion to *"define spark.utils.DataItem in the top-level application"* isn't clear to me. Is that an `#import`?

> warning: The class spark.utils.DataItem has been used in a call to
>   net.registerClassAlias()  in _ShoppingCart_FlexInit. This will cause
>   modules:ShoppingCart to be leaked.  To resolve the leak, define
>   spark.utils.DataItem in the top-level application.

---

`DataItem` reference:

```
    <s:typicalItem>
        <s:DataItem eventID = "eEventIDNum" 
                    eventName="eEventName" 
                    eventLocation="local" 
                    eventText1="I am a very long text description"  
                    eventLinkName="Summary"/>
    </s:typicalItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code is auto-generated by the [mxmlc compiler](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fcc.html), so you could try to use the compiler option `keep-generated-actionscript=true` to find the `registerClassAlias` call.

To follow the suggestion you could just define a `DataItem` dummy variable in the top-level application.

Comment: found it – and added the line `flash.net.registerClassAlias("spark.utils.DataItem", spark.utils.DataItem);` in the top-level app and the warning went away. Odd.